# I'm trying to scrap Stocks Data , Get requests method is working but is not giving data

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

First of all,
Thank you for your help.

I'm trying to create a stock data scraper based on the [Frankfurt](https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en) website.

I'm trying to get the historical prices section of the website.

I inspected the elements with chrome and I found an API in the network section.
[image]

Here is the response and preview on the network section.
[image]
[image]

I tried to use the code below :
[image]

When I run my script :
[image]

The code response seems good, but there is nothing in return.

I also tried to use BeautifulSoup to get my ways but I can't find where is located the data.

Here is what I tried :
[image]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why that the resquest return nothing is because that the data you want to scrape are rendered by javascript.
So first check out if the web data are rendered by javascript, if it is, try to use selenium or puppeteer to get those data.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, it seems that it's rendered by javascript.